# how would i allow non-root users to install, but only from a repo

Tags: apt, software-installation, permissions, ppa

i would like people on my system to install packages as long as it is always from a repo, and not a .deb package,or tar.gz,etc. how would i go about this? a good example of this would be to allow, say `apt install firefox`, but not `apt-get install ./firefox.deb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can blacklist all the packages ending in ".deb".
To do so you need to modify your "Never-MarkAuto-Sections" block in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove file.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove
```

The content of "Never-MarkAuto-Sections" should look like this:

```
  Never-MarkAuto-Sections
  {
    "metapackages";
    "contrib/metapackages";
    "non-free/metapackages";
    "restricted/metapackages";
    "universe/metapackages";
    "multiverse/metapackages";
  };
```

Add another entry at the end:

```
  Never-MarkAuto-Sections
  {
    "metapackages";
    "contrib/metapackages";
    "non-free/metapackages";
    "restricted/metapackages";
    "universe/metapackages";
    "multiverse/metapackages";
    "*.deb";
  };
```

Comment: how would i allow non-root users to install packages then?. is it a chroot modification? i dont even know where apt is installed...

Comment: Run "sudo visudo" and add this entry: "nonrootuser ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get install" doing like this nonrootuser can now use apt-get install without sudo password, that's very wrong and risky though.